# time locking policy script native asset

Tags: mainnet

I want to ensure a fixed supply of a native asset and this can be ensured by time locking of the policy id using the policy.script below:

```
    {
  "type": "all",
  "scripts":
  [
    {
      "type": "before",
      "slot": <insert slot here>
    },
    {
      "type": "sig",
      "keyHash": "insert keyHash here"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above format is created and run. Following error is shown

```
Syntax error in script: Error in $: "atLeast" script value not found
```

when the following command is run:

```
cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file policy.script
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your `keyHash` is correctly generated.

```
cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file policy.vkey
```

I tried your script with correct values and it's working.

Comment: Found the error. I had put the slot as a string instead of integer.

Comment: Great, in you script supposedly it was an integer because I didn't see any quotes.